# redux-saga does not work using "all" or "fork", but works with both

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-saga, saga

I have a redux saga called `newsSaga` (code shown below).

When I execute one of these, `newsSaga` **does not** get executed:

- `yield all([(newsSaga)]);`
- `yield [fork(newsSaga)];`

But when I execute this, `newsSaga` **does** get executed:

- `yield all([fork(newsSaga)]);`

I am verifying this by checking whether the `console.log` statement in `newsSaga.js` logs or not.

Why does this happen?

#### `rootSaga.js`

```js
import { all,fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {newsSaga} from './newsSaga.js';

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(newsSaga)
    ]);
}
```

#### `newsSaga.js`

```js
import {  all, call, put , takeLatest, select} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {getNews} from '@src/services/api.js';
import {newsJsonConverter} from '@src/common/tools.js';
import {NEWS_FETCH_REQUESTED} from '@src/actions';

export function* newsSaga() {
    console.log("inside newsSaga");
    yield takeLatest(NEWS_FETCH_REQUESTED, fetchNews);
  }
function* fetchNews(action) {
    /*implementation not important*/
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to run newsSaga you can just call that saga in your rootSaga and make that saga run.

Instead of

```
yield all([(newsSaga)]);
```

Try below code -

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
   yield all([newsSaga()]);
}
```

You have to call the generator function